# How do I support multiple flyway migrations within the same schema?

Tags: flyway

We have a single Database with a schema per tenant. We have multiple microservices, each with their own database migration scripts. These microservice tables are created within each tenant schema.

It appears that the flyway schema history table does not support this use case of having multiple independent migrations in the same schema. I tried creating a different schema history table (one per microservice), but then Flyway complained about needing to baseline. Currently I am baselining on every migration, which seems wrong.

What is the canonical way to handle this use case in Flyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use Flyway migration with single schema and multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753948/how-can-i-use-flyway-migration-with-single-schema-and-multiple-projects)